# Is it possible to add the Case Number to manual emails automatically?

Tags: email, case, email2case

I'm looking for a way to automatically include the Case Number in the subject line of an email when one of our agents starts a new email thread from a Case. I know this can be done manually, however it is forgotten more often than not, ideally I would like to do this without the use of templates as most of our responses are bespoke and therefor would likely come across the same issue.

Salesforce offers this natively for the Thread ID;

> (Settings > Customise > Cases > Email-to-Case > Insert Thread ID in
>   the Email Subject)

But I'm looking to replicate this for the Case Number as from a User Experience POV it's not great and confuses our customers when they are dealing with multiple reference numbers and formats.

(N.B. the Thread ID is included in the Email Body to ensure incoming responses are attached to the correct Case)

Comment: have you already tried the url hack? http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-email-url-hack-tutorial/

Comment: The URL hack works, in that it can populate the Subject line with the Case Number, but it gives the user the option to overwrite it as this is done on the email page rather than after hitting send. This wasn't considered ideal but it looks to be the best option we have available.